# Keyboard Acting Weird

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard

Today morning I started experiencing this weird problem,

*When trying to type something, if Left-Shift key is pressed the cursor goes left and if Right-Shift key is pressed the cursor goes right.

*If space bar is pressed, system volume gets lowered.
*If NumLock is pressed, system volume gets raised.

*Num pad keys 1&4 working as Shift-Key.

Sticky keys is not running.
OS: Windows 8.1.

Already tried re-plugging the keyboard and rebooting the system.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked for virus?

Comment: Made a scan, seems clear.

Comment: Use a 2nd antivirus. Malwarebytes is free.

Comment: That's exactly what I downloaded just now and now gonna initiate a scan.

Comment: @Xavierjazz  No threats found :(

Comment: Is your ON-Screen Keyboard working fine? Please check that.

Comment: @selah1936 that is working perfectly fine! No problems at all.

Comment: Then this type of problem occurs due to installation of third party utility also. Did you recently added some third party software?

Comment: @selah1936 My pc was off last night and today morning that error was fixed! Idk how but fixed...